# Applying for Turkish visa after refused once

Tags: visas, turkey, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladesh National. I applied for a Turkey tourist visa in 2014 from Bangladesh, but the application was not successful. The embassy didn't explain anything, but I think my passport was almost blank so they didn't think me genuine. Another reason might be that I had a refusal stamp of a UK visa in my passport. They put me a stamp on the last page "Applied for Turkey Visa."

Since then, I came to UK and now I am in Manchester. I have a UK residence permit. I need to go to Turkey again, this time for a medical purpose, not for tourism. I asked the Embassy whether I need to apply for visa, or I can use an e-visa. They replied by saying I need to apply for a visa at the consulate.

While applying online, it asked whether I was previously refused any Turkish visa. Should I say 'yes?' A friend told me that, if I have been refused once, then they might not issue me visa and create extra hassle.

Another problem is that I lost the passport with which I applied to Turkey the first time. If I say yes, will the embassy want to see the old passport? Do they check their database before issuing a visa to verify applicant's claim? I have all the other requirements fulfilled i.e., income, visa status etc. but not sure the first time refusal will give me trouble to get the visa.

Comment: Are you asking our opinion whether to tell **the truth** which is that you indeed were refused a visa previously? Whether they would want to see the old passport or not doesn't change the requirement that you have to be honest.

Comment: Yes I have to be honest but I want to know being honest here will bring me added trouble.

Comment: 2014 is not very long ago so the chances that they would be able to find out about the prior refusal are good. Your circumstances have changed a lot. Just tell the truth

Comment: If you lie about it, a refusal is guaranteed. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 8):

If you claim you were never refused a visa, and they find out you were (which they most likely will; they have computers and stuff in Turkey), you can probably say good-bye to any chance entering Turkey for many years.

Your chances of getting a visa are a lot better now as a UK resident. The question is always whether (a) they want you in the country for a short time, and (b) they believe you when you say you will be going back home. As a UK resident, those chances are a lot better.

Someone else says "it is less likely they will check all your records". Most likely someone types in your name and birth date, and your complete records will appear on their screen. It's probably completely automatic.

Will being honest get you into trouble? Being refused a visa earlier may be trouble. Being honest is *not* going to get you into trouble, since they will figure it out anyway.

PS. (Assuming Jiara changed his name to Gregory): With your additional information: It means what it says - your visa application has been forwarded to Turkish local authorities. That's not good or bad.

Your visa application was probably given to someone initially who is only allowed to handle the simplest cases, and that person passed it on to someone with more authority in Turkey, not in the UK.

The reasons why your visa was refused the first time are gone. You had a refusal for a UK visa in your passport back then, but now you are actually a UK resident so that refusal shouldn't logically count anymore, so right now I would be optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

You applied from Bangladesh Embassy and now you will be applying from UK. So there is less chance embassy will check all the records. And the online application system was introduced in Turkey last year. So even if you say, its less likely they will find it out. Yes they are able to find that out, but usually they are not meant to do. But, it will be dishonest to hide the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Turkey Embassy will find out if you give false information and probably you will be banned to get in country at least for 10 years. You may have a better chance with UK recidency but if only you be honest with them. You can't fool computers and Turkish government. They track everyone and you are in their system.